# Defining sed command in a groovy string

Tags: groovy, sed

I am trying to create this as a groovy string:

```
sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\n/g'
```

In groovy I have tried:

```
def sedCommand = "sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\n/g'"
```

but it gives : `Groovy:unexpected char: '\' @...`

I have tried various quotation, back slashing etc. but it keeps complaining.

Eventually the sed expression will be used like this:

```
Process process = [ 'bash', '-c', "curl -k --silent -X GET --insecure --silent $URL | hxselect '#token' | sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\n/g' " ].execute()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try ``def sedCommand = /sed 's\/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*\/\1\n\/g'/``

Comment: you have to escape with ` \ ` each ` \ ` and ` " ` chars in the string. or escape just `/` in the regular expression declaration: `def sedCommand = "sed 's/" + /.*value="\([^"]*\)".*\/\1\n/ + "/g'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [slashy string](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) where you only need to escape forward slashes and keep the rest as is:

```
def sedCommand = /sed 's\/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*\/\1\n\/g'/
```

It will represent

```
sed 's/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1\n/g'
```

See the [online Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/ZY7Zz5)